# Des / les civils meurent dans les / des villes et les / des campagnes de France

Tags: articles

Bonjour,

*En l'absence des hommes* de Philippe Besson :

> J'ai seize ans. Je suis né avec le siècle.
>
> Je sais qu'il y a la guerre, que **des** soldats meurent sur **les**
> fronts de cette guerre, que **des** civils meurent dans **les** villes
> et **les** campagnes de France et d'ailleurs...

L'auteur a écrit "**des** soldats" parce que ce ne sont pas **tous** les soldats qui meurent, mais est-il possible d'écrire "**des** civils meurent dans **des** villes
et **des** campagnes de France et d'ailleurs" ou faut-il parler en général ? Et si on parle en général, serait-il possible d'écrire "**les** civils meurent dans **les** villes et **les** campagnes de France et d'ailleurs" ?

Answer (score 2):

Il est tout à fait possible de choisir « des », mais alors on ne présente plus la même idée, et on dit seulement  que dans certaines villes et campagnes il y a des civils qui meurent. Néanmoins, cette idée serait le plus souvent communiquée en utilisant le déterminant indéfini "certain", par exemple.

- Je sais qu'il y a la guerre, que des soldats meurent sur les fronts de cette guerre, que des civils meurent dans **des** villes et **des** campagnes de France et d'ailleurs...
- Je sais qu'il y a la guerre, que des soldats meurent sur les fronts de cette guerre, que des civils meurent dans **certaines** villes et  campagnes de France et d'ailleurs...

« Des » n'est pas habituel dans ce contexte à moins qu'un modificateur soit ajouté.

- Je sais qu'il y a la guerre, que des soldats meurent sur les fronts de cette guerre, que des civils meurent dans **des** villes et **des** campagnes de France et d'ailleurs **qui sont ont gardé un esprit patriotique profond**...
- Je sais qu'il y a la guerre, que des soldats meurent sur les fronts de cette guerre, que des civils meurent dans **des** villes **acharnées contre l'ennemi**, **des** campagnes **insoumises**, en France et d'ailleurs...

Il existe une distinction subtile à garder à l'esprit et que l'on peut peut-être percevoir au moyen d'un exemple supplémentaire.

- Il y a des gens qui meurent dans leurs habitations ; en fait c'est ce qui arrive à la plupart des gens.

*Le nom « habitation » ne communique qu'une notion de lieu très général, sans connotations, d'où le manque de naturel dans l'utilisation de « des ». Un autre déterminant est nécessaire.*

- Il y a des gens qui meurent dans des taudis.

*Le nom « taudis » ne communique plus simplement qu'une notion de lieu, sans connotations, mais en plus une particularité devient apparente, d'où une légitimation (par l'usage) de l'utilisation de « des » ; cela rejoint le concept de la justification de « des » par modification : « des habitations qui sont insalubres ».*

- Il y a des gens qui meurent dans des habitations qui sont insalubres.

Comment: Merci beaucoup, LPH.

Answer (score 1):

1. *Est-il possible d'écrire "des civils meurent dans des villes et des campagnes de France et d'ailleurs"*

Oui, bien sûr, et c'est plus conforme à la logique. L'article défini est ici emphatique.

2. *Et si on parle en général, serait-il possible d'écrire "les civils meurent dans les villes et les campagnes de France et d'ailleurs" ?*

Pas vraiment, la phrase n'est ni très naturelle ni claire. De quels civils parle-t-on ? Ne peuvent-ils pas mourir à la montagne ou à la mer ?

Comment: Est-ce que tu sais pourquoi il possible d'écrire avec emphase "dans les villes et les campagnes" et non "les civils meurent", aussi pour souligner le phénomène ?

Comment: On peut vouloir dire que toutes les villes et les campagnes voient des civils mourir, le message est que des civils originaires de toutes les villes et campagnes de France meurent (au front), ce qui est certainement le cas avec le million et demi de morts français de la première guerre mondiale, mais si on dit *les civils* et que le contexte n'a pas précisé que l'on parlait d'un groupe précis, on dit que **toute** la population civile meurt, ce qui est plus que de l'emphase.

Comment: jlliagre, est-il possible de mettre l'article défini dans ta phrase au lieu de l'article partitif ? _on dit que toute la population civile meurt, ce qui est plus que **de l**'emphase._ Je pense que l'article défini devrait aussi être correct, non ?

Comment: *Ce qui est plus que l'emphase* ne marche pas. Ici, on parle de la mesure d'une caractéristique que l'on ne peut pas dénombrer. C'est une gradation continue. un texte est plus ou moins emphatique.