# Les / des hurlements de rage, les / des marteaux levés, les / des visages décomposés

Tags: articles

En saisissant des outils, B. et ses amis s'approchent de A. et l'encerclent. A. frappe B. au visage.

> Il hurle, puis la scène se joue au ralenti. **Les** hurlements de rage,
> **les** marteaux levés, **les** visages décomposés.

D'après l'une des réponses à cette [question](https://french.stackexchange.com/questions/48456/des-les-civils-meurent-dans-les-des-villes-et-les-des-campagnes-de-france), il est possible de mettre l'article défini dans la deuxième phrase. Il serait emphatique.

Aussi, c'est A. qui est le narrateur, et il décrit la scène.

Pourtant, j'ai des doutes. Est-ce que l'article défini est correct ici ?

Answer (score 3):

Étant averbale, cette phrase permet beaucoup de libertés. On a ici le choix entre articles définis, indéfinis et même celui de ne pas utiliser d'article du tout :

> Il hurle, puis la scène se joue au ralenti. Hurlements de rage, marteaux levés, visages décomposés.